# php pdo with js pagination

Tags: php, pdo

First to describe situation. My index page is divided with two div regions where my news articles are shown. Every part left and second have its one pagination, so user doesnt need to refresh page. 
Everything works with my old code, now I'm changing these old code to php pdo to prevent sql inj. attacks ant to update myself :)

Basically everything goes well until now. Maybe its too late or is something else, this should be simpe solution cause I have already working solution on my left side of the page. Difference is only in selecting characters and Category name from which should select text. 
Here's code:
Working code, on left part of the page

```
$offset = ($pageNum - 1) * $rowsPerPage;
$selectString = '%News-BlockLeft%';
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT ... " .
        "FROM News, Categories, NewsCheck " .  
        "WHERE Name LIKE :selectString " .
        "ORDER BY `NewsDate` DESC LIMIT :offset, :rowsPerPage");  

$STH->bindParam(':selectString ', $selectString, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$STH->bindParam(':rowsPerPage', $rowsPerPage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$STH->execute();
```

these code will fire onclick js which will return second page as follow

```
if ($pageNum > 1) {
    $opage = $pageNum - 1;
    $prev = "<a href=\"javascript:goToPage(" . $opage . ");\"><img src=\"/firstPage.gif\" /> </a>";
    $first = "<a href=\"javascript:goToPage(" . $opage . ");\">[<<]</a>";
} else {
    $prev = '';  // we're on page one, don't enable 'previous' link
    $first = ' <font size=\"3\">[<<] </font>'; // nor 'first page' link
}
```

ajaxRequest.js

```
function goToPage(page) {
    xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlhttp==null) {
        alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
        return;
    }
    var url="myPageBlockLeft.php";
    url=url+"?opage="+page;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 || xmlhttp.readyState=="complete") {
            document.getElementById('contentRight').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            initLightbox();
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

Select string is almost the same, on the left side which is working I select

```
WHERE Name LIKE :selectString
```

and on the other which not working I need to select `Where Name=:selectString`

Hope question is not sound too confused, cause I'm tired, if you need more info, please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dunno what is your problem but `WHERE Name='%News-BlockLeft%'` condition will hardly return any rows.

You need to run ll your queries in mysql console first, to see if they are working.
Only after that you may start to build them dynamically.

Also note that `WHERE Name LIKE '%News-BlockLeft%'` is a huge design flaw.
You have to use some distinct parameter to designate left block news, not this home-brewed string comparison.